# Simple MySQL CONCAT function

Tags: mysql

This function should skip digits from 0 to 9 - nothing else. Why does it also skip blanks? E.g. strip_digits("St. Johnes") results in "St.Johnes"

```
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(255) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str );
  SET ret = '';
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF ASCII(c)<ASCII('0') OR ASCII(c)>ASCII('9') THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`.
When `CHAR` values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length. When `CHAR` values are retrieved, trailing spaces are removed.

You can read it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

change both 'ret' and 'c' to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: That does it. Good lesson. Thank you so much!